# Replacing inner HTML fails despite onload function

Tags: javascript, html

I rarely have to do any Javascript and I seem to fail doing the easiest tasks. I am trying to replace a string in two divs. The first div gets replaced, the second one is not found with the error message:

drawings.html:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of     null

However I tried the usual remedies of putting my code in an 'onload' function and putting the script at the end of the body tag. What else could possibly go wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="cell1">test<div>
<div id="cell2">test<div>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  replace();
}

function replace() {
  console.log("replace");
  document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = "cell1";
  document.getElementById("cell2").innerHTML = "cell2";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Closing div(`</div>`) is missing. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dtztc8fm/1/

Comment: I had to be something trivial as that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just close your `divs` elements.

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="cell1">test</div>
<div id="cell2">test</div>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  replace();
}

function replace() {
  console.log("replace");
  document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = "cell1";
  document.getElementById("cell2").innerHTML = "cell2";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That dosent work all the time. If you dont believe me, click on the Run Code Snippet Multiple times continously.

Comment: Not at all @John I clicked 10 times didnt work fine the last one

Comment: Not at all @RayonDabre . I can show a viedo if you want

Comment: Do share it...Will be fun I guess.. Why would that fail ? Any guesses ?

Comment: Test it out in few other machines..I did test it in 3 machines in different browsers and I could not reproduce it..